# Nodejs + Firefox behavior in relation to the HTML5 <audio> element

Tags: html, node.js, firefox, audio

I am using Nodejs and Firefox to display a web page. That page has a HTML5 audio element. The problem I have is related to the calcul of the audio duration. 
In my node js script I have:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , path = require("path")
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')
  , exec = require('child_process').exec
  , spawn = require ('child_process').spawn
  , util = require('util')
  , extensions = {
  ".html": "text/html",
  ".css": "text/css",
  ".js": "application/javascript",
  ".png": "image/png",
  ".gif": "image/gif",
  ".ttf": "application/x-font-ttf",
  ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
  ".mp3": "audio/mp3",
  ".wav": "audio/wav",
  ".ogg": "audio/ogg"
}
  , Files = {};
```

In my html web page I have:

```
<audio  id="idaudio"  src="" type="audio/wav" >Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
```

And some javascript code from my web page:

```
var thissound=document.getElementById("idaudio");
    thissound.src="http://localhost/Audio/Song.wav";
    //thissound.src="/Audio/Song.wav";

thissound.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {

    var durationaudio = (thissound.duration)*1000;
         });
```

When I check the durationaudio I get the right number and then I can play the song using `thissound.play()`; This code is working in Firefox and Chromium.

If I change

```
thissound.src="http://localhost/Audio/Song.wav" -> thissound.src="/Audio/Song.wav"
```

Adding  the ".wav": "audio/wav" extension in the node script, I can play the Song using Firefox and Chromium; In Chromium I get also the right number of the `durationaudio` but using Firefox I get a `durationaudio=Infinity`. This is the problem. I dont know why Firefox is not able to get the right duration. Maybe I have to add some extension ... in the node script in order to allow Firefox to get the duration of the audio. Any ideas?

Comment: If this requests the same audio resource, then it should not matter whether it is requested via an absolute or a relative URL. Have you compared the headers for both requests/responses, any differences? Can you post a link to an online example?

Comment: Hi, How ca I do to compare the headers? I can't post a link...

Comment: Firebug, net panel … but without a live example you’re on your own from here on.

Comment: I have used http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/ and comparing headers I have seen that the Content-Range was missing.... I have added in my node script: 'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + contents.length + '-' + 1 + '/' + contents.length, 
    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',                             And now it seems to work. You were right, if was a headers problem... thanks